# wolframclient library and DJango

Tags: python, wolfram-client

I'm working on a project where a Django server needs to evaluate Wolfram Language code. Has anyone done this or know the best way to go about it?

I've got something working, using a static class with a WolframSession from the wolframclient library. However, whenever I save or ctrl+c to stop the server, it doesn't close, so I have to exit the entire terminal. Also, every 4 launches I've got to go into task manager and end all the Wolfram Kernel processes. This makes development a hassle.

Any ideas?

Thank you